# how to make green color body using using is_grater_priority

Tags: django

`class Todolist(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
detail = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
created = models.CharField(max_length=255)
is_grater_priority=models.BooleanField(default=False)`
```

*****i have done this, but not working***** Now what should i do to  make this workable

`
{% if list %}

```
        {% for obj in list %}

        {% if obj == is_grater_priority %}

        <p class="text-success"><strong>Title:- </strong> {{obj.title}} </p>
        <p class="text-success"><strong>Details:- </strong> {{obj.detail}} </p>
        <p class="text-success"><strong>Sheduled:- </strong> {{obj.created}} </p>
        <a href="{% url 'todolist:edit_todolist' obj.id %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'todolist:delete_todolist' obj.id %}">Delete</a>
        <hr>

        {% else %}
        <p><strong>Title:- </strong> {{obj.title}} </p>
        <p><strong>Details:- </strong> {{obj.detail}} </p>
        <p><strong>Sheduled:- </strong> {{obj.created}} </p>
        <a href="{% url 'todolist:edit_todolist' obj.id %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'todolist:delete_todolist' obj.id %}">Delete</a>
        <hr>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <h2>No list avilable</h2>
        {% endif %}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your if statement isn't accessing the boolean field.

Try changing this.

```
{% if obj == is_grater_priority %}
```

To this

```
{% if obj.is_grater_priority %}
```

That should check to see if the boolean is true.